# /range option for graph API accessing a excel file on Sharepoint (with table) results in 400 response

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Since 01/29/2022 the below get request is resulting in a 400 response

```
v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/items/{doc_id}/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/tables/{table_name}/range
```

whereas

```
v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/items/{doc_id}/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/tables/{table_name} 

v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/items/{doc_id}/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/tables/{table_name}/rows
```

results in a 200 response.

The http headers payloads are accurate (Authorization, content type)

Here is my python Code

**Note: the code below (and above) - the sensitive information has been redacted.**

```
import requests

url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{organization share point site}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{document-id}/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/tables/{table name}/range'
print (url)
http_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {my key}', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'verify' : 'True'}
x = requests.get(url=url,headers=http_headers,stream=False)
print(x.status_code)
```

Comment: It's working for me. Did you make any changes to a table?

Comment: no we did not make any changes - unfortunately.

Comment: Is there a size limit to the table in excel that the range can read ?

Comment: I don't think so. How big is your table? I will create the table with same size and try to get range.

Comment: I do not think it is size because we experimented with a smaller size table, 2 rows but 30 columns and we still get the same 400 status code.

Comment: but the strange part of this is that the /rows works and we get the response back - just the /range fails.

Comment: but just to answer your question - size - it is about 32k rows and 30 columns

Comment: Turns out @user2250152 is correct - thank you. It was the unspoken, unwritten size limit that caused the issue. We also figured that our last test (with 2 rows) was not accurate - we did not change the document id (referencing the previous excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is too large you can receive response status 400 with the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResponsePayloadSizeLimitExceeded",
        "message": "The size of the payload exceeded the limit. Read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/resource-limits-and-performance-optimization#excel-add-ins.",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "responsePayloadSizeLimitExceeded",
            "message": "The size of the payload exceeded the limit. Read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/resource-limits-and-performance-optimization#excel-add-ins.",
            "date": "2022-02-01T12:38:03",
            "request-id": "cae21c5d-8a48-4a22-ad4d-8994de9325ef",
            "client-request-id": "7a46b35e-7f15-1d22-75c3-dd867d0d48b5"
        }
    }
}
```